# How do I mock document.getElementsByClassName() in jest and react-testing-library for the code-coverage?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

How can we mock document.getElementsByClassNames() in jest/ react-testing-library , since these part of the code is not been covered in code-coverage

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    const headings = [...document.getElementsByClassName("heading")];

    if(!!headings.length){
      console.log("DO SOMETHING !!")
    }
    headings?.map((heading) => {
      return heading.setAttribute("id", "header-toggle");
    });
    
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {numbers?.map((num) => {
        return <h1 className="heading">{num}</h1>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App'

afterEach(cleanup);

  it('render App', () => {

document.getElementsByClassName() = jest.fn().mockImplementation([{setAttribute:jest.fn()}])

    const { container } = render(<App/>); 
    expect(container).toBeInTheDocument()
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mock `document.getElementsByClassName()` and test the implementation detail. Instead, test the component's behavior such as what the component renders.

You can assert if the `id` HTML attribute is set correctly or not.

E.g.

`App.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const headings = [...document.getElementsByClassName('heading')];

    if (!!headings.length) {
      console.log('DO SOMETHING !!');
    }
    headings.map((heading, i) => {
      return heading.setAttribute('id', `header-toggle-${i}`);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {numbers.map((num) => {
        return <h1 key={num} className="heading">{num}</h1>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`App.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import App from './App';

describe('App', () => {
  it('render App', () => {
    const { container } = render(<App />);
    expect(container).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('render App with numbers', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<App />);
    const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    numbers.forEach((n, i) => {
      expect(getByText(`${n}`)).toBeInTheDocument();
      expect(getByText(`${n}`).id).toEqual(`header-toggle-${i}`);
    });
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/72626153/App.test.tsx (9.755 s)
  App
    ✓ render App (40 ms)
    ✓ render App with numbers (21 ms)

  console.log
    DO SOMETHING !!

      at stackoverflow/72626153/App.tsx:10:15

  console.log
    DO SOMETHING !!

      at stackoverflow/72626153/App.tsx:10:15

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 App.tsx  |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 9                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.256 s, estimated 11 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files
```

Comment: Thanks !! , but u can see uncovered lines at 9 , actually I have 100+ lines of code inside if block those code are not covered. any way to cover those code

Comment: @Hitheshk Install a spy on `console.log` like `const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');`. And check assert `logSpy.toBeCalled()`. Besides, `headings` will never be empty. So the `if (!!headings.length)` is unnecessary